# Is there a way to share sound cloud widget as a post to Facebook for iOS native code

Tags: ios, facebook, soundcloud

I am very new to sound cloud. I am successful in uploading music to soundcloud using [soundcloud SDK for iOS](https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI). Now I need to share the uploaded soundcloud music as soundcloud widget in Facebook. Can any one please let me know how it can be done.